# What does a hash sign '#' do in printf()?

Tags: c, printf

```
int x = 0xff;
printf("%#x",x);
```

Output: `0xff`

```
printf("%x",x);
```

Ouput: `ff`

Why is there a difference in output? What does `#` specifically do?

Comment: If you google "printf pound sign" the answer is in the first result...

Comment: @GordonBailey, never would have though to look it up under "pound sign". But I would have had the idea to simply look into the manual page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard says:

> 7.21.6 - 2
>
> The result is converted to an ‘‘alternative form’’.  ... For x (or X)
>   conversion, a nonzero result has 0x (or 0X) preﬁxed to it.

It does other interesting stuff (especially for floats) but I have rarely seen it used - I honestly admit I had to look it up to remember.

Comment: Note that the prefix only gets added if the value is non-zero, and the 0x/0X appears in the same case as the hex digits. This is rarely/never what I want with hex, so I always use `0x%X` rather than `%#x` or %#X`...

Answer (score 2):

The `#` flag behaves different for different types. Wikipedia has a good summary:

> For g and G types, trailing zeros are not removed.
>
> For f, F, e, E, g, G types, the output always contains a decimal point.
>
> For o, x, X types, the text 0, 0x, 0X, respectively, is prepended to non-zero numbers.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Flags_field