# I don't understand the flag # with %f on printf

Tags: c, printf

i'm actually recoding printf for a school project.
I have to do %f, and i don't see what the flag #f is doing, I think that if he's here that's for a reason and i don't find it.
Thanks guys !

Comment: Read the documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a hash sign '#' do in printf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922876/what-does-a-hash-sign-do-in-printf)

Comment: ...or this [What the hash sign do in the following statement [duplicate] statement] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694404/what-the-hash-sign-do-in-the-following-)

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function, p.#6)

> For a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, the result of converting a
>   floating-point number always contains a decimal-point character, even
>   if no digits follow it. (Normally, a decimal-point character appears in the 
>   result of these conversions only if a digit follows it.) For g and G
>   conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from the result.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    float value = 10.0f;

    printf( "%.0f\n", value );
    printf( "%#.0f\n", value );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
10
10.
```

As it is seen in the second output the decimal point is used.

Comment: Also trailing zeroes are not removed in `g` and `G` formats.

Comment: “p.” is commonly used as an abbreviation for “page,” and using it for “paragraph” may confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

[CppReference.com on printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> #: alternative form of the conversion is performed.

And then with regards to the `%f` conversion:

> In the alternative implementation decimal point character is written even if no digits follow it.